# Should I ask for positive/negative feedback on a chat system?

Tags: user-feedback, chat

I'm building a chat to use on my admin dashboard, where my clients interact with the company and ask for support. On this windows, I'm thinking about using a feedback button, to see how my clients are rating this system.

This is the screen I'm using (under development):

[image]

Whit this in mind, I have 2 main doubts:

Should I place the feedback right at the beginning of the conversation, as soon as the chat start? Or after some time/amount of messages?

Also, is it ok to ask only for positive feedback? Or should I keep the "Dislike" button so clients are able to "Dislike"?

The main purpose with this is to evaluate the chat system itself, and what they think about this new method, not the conversation or the topic discussed on the conversation.

Comment: Asking users for feedback like that may be a bad idea, because it's in front of him all the time and he has to answer to get rid of it... and it may increase the dislikes! Google asks for feedback for their services from time to time, maybe it can be helpful to you :)

Comment: I don't have any ideas for the UX, but there is a grammar mistake - "liked" should be "like" - "Did you like our chat?", or, even better, "Did you enjoy this chat?".

Comment: @Jojodmo oh, thanks. But also english is not my native language, so this isn't a problem. :)

Comment: @Jack-in-the-box maybe a dismiss button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the **Like and Dislike options may not reflect the true opinion** of a user. There can be a scenario where User neither liked or disliked your chat. Like on a scale on say 0 to 5, User wants to say 3. At present you are only giving him a system where he can either enter 0 (*dislike*) or enter 5 (*like*).

> So c**onsider using a rating** system on a scale on 1 - 5 like below

[image]

Now, for your question, **feedback is asked after the service** has been provided. So you can a cross (X) at the top left as an option to close window. When user clicks on it, that time you can ask for the feedback - after all that is the best time one can provide feedback.

[image]

Also, it is a good practice to include a "*Later*" option in the feedback, as not every user want to fill that form right away. So, when a user chooses *later*, you can mail them with a link to provide feedback !